# Custom css for application pages in angular using Keycloak

Tags: java, angular, keycloak

I am trying to set up Keycloak for multi tenant application in angular.I have created realms in Keycloak and integrated in angular app.For login page theme is applied from keycloak. After user is logged in, for dashboard and other application pages I want css to get applied from Keycloak themes.Is it possible using Keycloak to apply css for application pages?What is the better way to do this?

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but do you want to change the internal theme in Keycloak admin pages or in your angular app?. If you want to change Keycloack theme you can do it by creating your own Theme. If what you want is to use the same keycloak's theme in Angular you will have to create your own css in your angular app in order to match it with Keycloak css.

Comment: I want to change in angular app.that custom css I want to load it from Keycloak.Is it possible?